# Filter and hide rows not working?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column that contains numbers and blank cells in it. The filter I have setup should hide the cells that are blank/empty; however, it doesn't seem to be working properly. For some reason it seems to hide blank cells until Autofiltermode is set to false. Please see my code below.

```
 With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    With .Range("A:BM")
        .AutoFilter Field:=65, Criteria1:=""
        On Error Resume Next
        .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Hidden
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
```

Comment: Are you not then removing the filter? False removes the drop down arrows

Comment: @qharr, I am removing the filters, though I was expecting that the hidden rows would stay hidden.

Comment: why would they? They are hidden because the filter is applied.

Comment: It sounds like there's a better way to go about this, then. I am attempting to hide the rows while I do other checks, and I went the return values of those checks to _only_ show in the rows where that particular filter column is not blank.

Comment: What is this line supposed to be doing `.Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Hidden`? And your filter is selecting the rows that are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Setting [.Autofilter = False](http://%20https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-autofiltermode-property-excel) removes the filter so you will see the rows that were hidden.

Instead look at `EntireRow.Hidden = True` and `False` to have hidden rows independent of the current filter.

You could collect the hidden rows into a union of range objects before removing the filter so you can hide them at any point later on.

Note I am setting a test range `.Range("A1:A5")` . This would be set in your data down to the last populated row that is of interest.

For last row methods see Ron De Bruin's [articles](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm).

```
Sub test()


With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    .AutoFilterMode = False

    With .Range("A:BM")

        .AutoFilter Field:=65, Criteria1:=vbNullstring

       Dim rng As Range
       Set rng = .Range("A1:A5")
       Dim aRow As Range
       Dim unionRng As Range

       For Each aRow In rng.Rows

           If aRow.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then 'were hidden because were blanks

               If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then

                   Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, aRow) 'store the "" rows in union range

               Else

                 Set unionRng = aRow

               End If

         End If

       Next aRow


    End With

    .AutoFilterMode = False

    If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then MsgBox unionRng.Address

    End With

End Sub
```

To hide you can now at any point say:

```
If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then unionRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

Comment: I've tried using entirerow.hidden = true; same result.

Comment: Did you cut the =True off of the posted code? Also be way of using specialcells

Comment: And add a check  to make sure more than one row present rather than just on error resume

Comment: And this  .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1, 0) is working with the whole sheet not just the range with data in

Comment: To use EntireRow.Hidden you need to have the range set to apply this to

Comment: Thanks for this, QHar,, though it only seems to hide the rows that do have the numbers in them.

Comment: See my comment in the question.. I set that range just as an example. If you have a look at the link I reference you can find different ways of determining the last row for your data then you put Range("A1:A" & lastRow)  .......... It is the principle which was answering your question as set and showing you an alternative way to think about things. Have a look at the link I gave.

Comment: Re the rows with data in - let me just check that!

Comment: the issue was that the line 'If aRow.EntireRow.Hidden = True Then' should have been 'If aRow.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then'

Comment: Slly me i am guessing. Yes I was focused on the hidden rows.

Comment: Updated answer. Sorry about that. Forgot that you cared about the  "". Have also swopped the empty string literal "" for vbNullString. More efficient. Does that now make sense? Autofilter false removed filter. If you want to keep track you can test the EntireRow.Hidden property whilst the filter is on and save the location of those rows for later use.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Autofilter as they pointed out in the comments. Try this code.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim lRow As Long

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lRow
        Cells(i, 65).EntireRow.Hidden = IsEmpty(Cells(i, 65).Value)
    Next i

'do other checks using SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Or

```
Dim i As Long
Dim lRow As Long

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lRow
    If Cells(i, 65).Value = "" Then
        Cells(i, 65).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next i
```